# Get excel row sum into variable instead of cell

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to retrieve the sum of a row from an excel document.
When googling this all of the solutions involved writing a `=SUM(1:1)` like formula into a cell and then writing the result to a variable.

Since I don't want to edit the excel file i was wondering if it's possible to retrieve the sum of a row range directly into a variable without the pit stop?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Your question is very vague. What framework / API are you using?

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using xlsx files you can use this cool lib :

https://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation

It uses `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` you can install `closedXml` and dependancies with this command :

```
Install-Package ClosedXML
```

Example to do a sum on the first row :

```
        //open the excel file
        var wb = new XLWorkbook("excel File path");

        //get the first worksheel
        var ws = wb.Worksheet(0);

        var lineNumber = 0;
        var startColumn = 0;
        var endColumn = 10;

        var cells = ws.Range(lineNumber, startColumn, lineNumber, endColumn).Cells().ToList();
        var sum = cells.Sum(xlCell => (int) xlCell.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will save the sum of the values of two cells into "myVariable"

```
    Dim myWB As Workbook
    Set myWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = myWB.Sheets(1)
    Dim myVariable As Variant
    myVariable = ws.Cells(1,1).Value + ws.Cells(2,1).Value
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm using C#